# while creating application session for google oauth 2 for ios returns invalid_grant

Tags: ios, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using google's OAuth2.0 process to let users sign within my iOS App.

After the `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` returns the `GTMOAuth2Authentication` i still have to 
create an own application session with my backend. I know this flow our website where it is working.

I already tried to validate the session by POSTing the `GTMOAuth2Authentication` auth code from to Google but i'll always get a `400 invalid_grant` error. 
(for testing porpuses i used Objective-C for the POST which would usually handled by our backend)

```
NSDictionary *data = @{
                           @"code":googleAuthCode,
                           @"redirect_url":@"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
                           @"client_secret":SD_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
                           @"client_id":SD_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
                           @"grant_type":@"authorization_code"
                           };


AFHTTPClient *google = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com"]];

NSString *path = @"/o/oauth2/token";
[google postPath:path parameters:data success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"responseObject %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failed %@",error);
}];`
```

any suggestion how to create the application session?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the gtm-oauth2 library:
https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/

Also check the documentation there:
https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction